# jQuery .click() not working in Internet Explorer 9/10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

The below is part of a larger project (obviously) and it's working fine in Chrome, Firefox and Opera but the .click() functions aren't being called by IE9 or 10.

```
jQuery('.current img').hover(function() {
    var thisElem = jQuery(this);

    thisElem.parent().parent().find('.hotspot span:not(.select-image)').remove();
    thisElem.parent().parent().find('.hotspot img').parent().find('span.select-image').remove();

    jQuery('<span class="zoom-out"></span>').prependTo(thisElem.parent()).click(function() {
        z -= .1;
        z = Math.max(z, 1);

        jQuery(this).parent().find('img').attr('src', '<?php echo $urlPrefix; ?>/zcard-thumbnail-image/photos/<?php echo $modelId; ?>/low/' + i + '/' + (w * z) + '/' + (h * z) + '/file');
    });

    jQuery('<span class="select-image"></span>').prependTo(thisElem.parent());

    jQuery('<span class="zoom-in"></span>').prependTo(thisElem.parent()).click(function() {
        z += .1;
        z = Math.min(z, 5);

        jQuery(this).parent().find('img').attr('src', '<?php echo $urlPrefix; ?>/zcard-thumbnail-image/photos/<?php echo $modelId; ?>/low/' + i + '/' + (w * z) + '/' + (h * z) + '/file');
    });
});
```

As far as I can tell, the .click() isn't binding because the elements don't yet exist. If I instead use jQuery(target).prepend(element), then an alert to delay further execution, and then the .click() binds, everything works fine. Unfortunately replacing the alerts with delay() doesn't result in the same.

Does anybody have suggestions please?

Comment: And you did of course declare `z`, `h` and `w` somewhere ?

Comment: Ha, I did =). It all works flawlessly in other browsers, and if I use alerts to cause a delay between creating the element and adding a bind to it, everything also work in IE9/10. It's as though IE is just too slow at updating the DOM to attach a bind immediately after creation.

Comment: It's a much older version but the same problem appears to be in this (a mock, wireframed build of part of the system I'm now trying to debug which I'm afraid I can't provide access to): http://development.qweb.co.uk/tim-bailey/zcard/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!

It turned out IE was triggering the hover event every time the mouse moved over the injected child elements, while other browsers were only triggering while hovering over the element that had the bind, as you'd expect.

event.stopPropagation wasn't working for me, so I faked it with the help of .data(). Here's the end result:

```
jQuery('.current img').hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('hover');
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.hotspot:not(.hover) span:not(.select-image)').remove();
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.hotspot:not(.hover) img').data('hovered', 'false');
    jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('hover');
    if(jQuery(this).data('hovered') != 'true') {
        jQuery(this).data('hovered', 'true');
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.hotspot span:not(.select-image)').remove();
        jQuery(this).parent().find('span.select-image').remove();
        jQuery(this).parent().prepend('<span class="zoom-in"></span><span class="select-image"></span><span class="zoom-out"></span>');

        jQuery(this).parent().find('.zoom-in').click(function() {
            z += .1;
            z = Math.min(z, 5);

            jQuery(this).parent().find('img').attr('src', '<?php echo $urlPrefix; ?>/zcard-thumbnail-image/photos/<?php echo $modelId; ?>/low/' + i + '/' + (w * z) + '/' + (h * z) + '/file');
        });

        jQuery(this).parent().find('.zoom-out').click(function() {
            z -= .1;
            z = Math.max(z, 1);

            jQuery(this).parent().find('img').attr('src', '<?php echo $urlPrefix; ?>/zcard-thumbnail-image/photos/<?php echo $modelId; ?>/low/' + i + '/' + (w * z) + '/' + (h * z) + '/file');
        });
    }
});
```

Massive thanks to everybody for helping with this one and I hope the above is useful to somebody experiencing similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you can create a selector to identify the elements, you could use [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to attach your handlers - that works for elements that don't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks Richie. .delegate() was deprecated by .on() and this isn't working either unfortunately. I think perhaps because when the .hover() finishes executing, any 'for future' binds get lost?

Comment: @Ric - Adding the event handler during the creation of an element as you are doing works fine without delegating the event, so that's not the problem, something else is. IE9/10 does have a console, are there any errors in the console. It's hard to debug your code with all the PHP and variables that are probably declared elsewhere etc.

Comment: The console shows no errors. If I put an alert inside the click event, IE doesn't trigger it suggesting the click is never reached so I can only assume the bind isn't sticking.

For the record, I've built this for jQuery 1.8 but have also tried 1.9 and 1.9.1 just in case something got fixed in the core.

Comment: Hmm... @adeneo, I thought I'd put together a basic sample script to show this not working in IE9/10 but somehow the sample works! It seems something else is indeed the problem here...

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it so I'm not sure if the delay is the problem anyway, but you can try delaying it with a manual setTimeout:

```
var zoomOutSpan = jQuery('<span class="zoom-out"></span>').prependTo(thisElem.parent());

setTimeout( function()
{
    zoomOutSpan.click(function() {
        z -= .1;
        z = Math.max(z, 1);

        jQuery(this).parent().find('img').attr('src', '<?php echo $urlPrefix; ?>/zcard-thumbnail-image/photos/<?php echo $modelId; ?>/low/' + i + '/' + (w * z) + '/' + (h * z) + '/file');
    });
}, 1) // just 1 milisecond to execute it on a new thread
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk - I really thought that idea would work, but it seems to not have any effect. I even tried splitting the first line out as follows:

    var zoomInSpan = jQuery('<span class="zoom-in"></span>');
    zoomInSpan.prependTo(thisElem.parent());

Comment: Gah, zoomInSpan = jQuery('<span class="zoom-in"></span>');alert('test');zoomInSpan.prependTo... works, but zoomInSpan = jQuery('<span class="zoom-in"></span>').delay(100).prependTo... fails :-/

Comment: zoomInSpan.prependTo(thisElem.parent()).delay(100).on('click', ... fails too. This is ridiculous!

Comment: Hey Ric, I'd like to help out. Is it possible that you set up an jsfiddle with a skeleton version of the specifc problem? If you add that to your question it makes it really easy for people to play around with your problem!

Comment: Thanks for jumping back on Dirk, but yes, it is indeed fixed now :-). Stack Overflow won't let me mark the answer until tomorrow for some reason. It's also not letting me mark any of these posts as useful because my rank isn't high enough yet, which I feel a little mean about!